# 503 "service-unavailable" error when querying for the archive of a given user (mod_mam)

Tags: java, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to query the archive of messages for a user in ejabberd (16.09 from jessie-backports) via [mod_mam](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html) (as indicated in **Example 2. A user queries their archive for messages**), but keep getting a "No module is handling this query" error.

The interaction with the server is being done with the [Babbler](https://bitbucket.org/sco0ter/babbler/) Java client.

Here is the custom payload class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "query", namespace = "urn:xmpp:mam:2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public final class UserMessageArchiveQuery {

  @XmlAttribute(name = "queryid")
  private String queryId;

  public UserMessageArchiveQuery() {}

  public String getQueryId() {
    return queryId;
  }

  public void setQueryId(String string) {
    this.queryId = string;
  }
}
```

Which is then being added to the session configuration.

```
XmppSessionConfiguration sessionConfiguration =
  XmppSessionConfiguration
    .builder()
    .extensions(Extension.of(UserMessageArchiveQuery.class))
    .build();
```

Now we can establish the connection, which works fine as I am able to send and receive messages accordingly.

```
XmppClient client = XmppClient.create("localhost", sessionConfiguration, tcpConfiguration, boshConfiguration);
client.connect();
client.login("someuser", password);
```

Here is where things go south. Preparing an IQ for a given user and payload, and querying the server:

```
UserMessageArchiveQuery payload = new UserMessageArchiveQuery();
IQ iq = IQ.set(Jid.of("someuser@localhost"), payload);
return client.query(iq).getResult();
```

Peeking at the ejabberd logs, the resulting XML that is being sent to the server is as follows:

```
<iq id="47a6204a-6ac3-453b-9dfd-7488ec6de734" to="someuser@localhost" type="set">
    <query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2"></query>
</iq>
```

To which we get:

```
packet {xmlel,<<"iq">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"error">>},{<<"from">>,<<"someuser@localhost">>},{<<"xml:lang">>,<<"en-US">>},{<<"id">>,<<"47a6204a-6ac3-453b-9dfd-7488ec6de734">>}],[{xmlel,<<"query">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:xmpp:mam:2">>}],[]},{xmlel,<<"error">>,[{<<"code">>,<<"503">>},{<<"type">>,<<"cancel">>}],[{xmlel,<<"service-unavailable">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">>}],[]},{xmlel,<<"text">>,[{<<"xmlns">>,<<"urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">>}],[{xmlcdata,<<"No module is handling this query">>}]}]}]}
```

I am certain that mod_mam is enabled and working properly, as I can see the archived messages in the "archive" table. I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 1):

ejabberd doesn't support urn:xmpp:mam:2 at the moment.